# How can i use the Drupal form API states to make my field value depend on another field value?

Tags: 7, javascript

Basically what I'm trying to do is to change the [`#autocomplete_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path) for the author field in the node/add.

The value of the [`#autocomplete_path`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#autocomplete_path) will be dependent on the value of another field (a select list field).

I want to do this because I made my own callback function for the autocomplete and that callback function must receive some arguments that depends on what the user will choose from another field.

Comment: What Drupal version you are using? I'm afraid it's relevant here.

Comment: I'm using Drupal 7.34

Comment: OK, I added Form API links to your question. I hope you already know it, but it might be useful for future readers. Have you tried to change this path already? With what code? And what was your result?